# É possível alterar o css do elemento pai quando ele houver um filho diferente?

Tags: css, css3

Com CSS, é possível modificar o CSS do pai se o filho tiver uma classe diferente sem que eu mude o nome da classe do pai? Só estou precisando na verdade trocar o fundo padrão da página, quando o conteúdo trocar..., em vez de ficar setando classe nova na div do fundo, gostaria de fazer isso apenas se o conteúdo mudar...

Exemplo, abaixo seria o padrão:

```
<div class="el-pai">
    
    <div class="el-filho"></div>

</div>
```

Daí o filho mudaria o nome da classe, e o `el-pai` ficaria com outra cor:

```
<div class="el-pai">
    
    <div class="el-filho-diferente"></div>

</div>
```

CSS padrão:

```
.el-pai {
   color: red;
}

.el-pai > .el-filho {
   color: blue;
}
```

Mudando o filho a cor mudaria para preto, por exemplo:

```
.el-pai {
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: Cara. depende muito da sua situação real ai. Se vc quer trocar o fundo apenas, pode ser que de jeito sim, usando por exemplo um pseudo elemento com position absolute no filho. Mas mudar o estilo do pai, dependendo se tem um filho com uma classe X dentro ainda não é possível só com CSS

Comment: "Ainda não é possível" e provavelmente nunca será. Já propuseram isso algumas vezes e nunca emplacou. Isso porque o CSS é todo baseado em herança e cascata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, não é possível. Se quer poder alterar pai e filho, precisa colocar a classe no elemento pai.

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei...